# Prestashop image resize - loss of quality

Tags: php, image, resize, prestashop, gd

I'm using the newest version of **Prestashop (1.6.1.5)**, and I've got some problems with **quality of product images.**

While resizing *(creating thumbnails like large_default, home_default etc)* grey stripes appears on destination image.

I followed prestashop code and noticed that it happens after *imagecopyresized()* function, I tried to replace it with *imagecopyresampled()* but it doesn't help much.

Here is a link to the original image http://postimg.org/image/ib42bh81t, and here is a link to resized one *(the one with grey stripes)* http://postimg.org/image/i3tpda7sx

**Prestashop *resize()* method:**

```
public static function resize($src_file, $dst_file, $dst_width = null, $dst_height = null, $file_type = 'jpg',
                            $force_type = false, &$error = 0, &$tgt_width = null, &$tgt_height = null, $quality = 5,
                            &$src_width = null, &$src_height = null)
{
    if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50300) {
        clearstatcache();
    } else {
        clearstatcache(true, $src_file);
    }

    if (!file_exists($src_file) || !filesize($src_file)) {
        return !($error = self::ERROR_FILE_NOT_EXIST);
    }

    list($tmp_width, $tmp_height, $type) = getimagesize($src_file);
    $rotate = 0;
    if (function_exists('exif_read_data') && function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
        $exif = @exif_read_data($src_file);

        if ($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 3:
                    $src_width = $tmp_width;
                    $src_height = $tmp_height;
                    $rotate = 180;
                    break;

                case 6:
                    $src_width = $tmp_height;
                    $src_height = $tmp_width;
                    $rotate = -90;
                    break;

                case 8:
                    $src_width = $tmp_height;
                    $src_height = $tmp_width;
                    $rotate = 90;
                    break;

                default:
                    $src_width = $tmp_width;
                    $src_height = $tmp_height;
            }
        } else {
            $src_width = $tmp_width;
            $src_height = $tmp_height;
        }
    } else {
        $src_width = $tmp_width;
        $src_height = $tmp_height;
    }

    // If PS_IMAGE_QUALITY is activated, the generated image will be a PNG with .jpg as a file extension.
    // This allow for higher quality and for transparency. JPG source files will also benefit from a higher quality
    // because JPG reencoding by GD, even with max quality setting, degrades the image.
    if (Configuration::get('PS_IMAGE_QUALITY') == 'png_all'
        || (Configuration::get('PS_IMAGE_QUALITY') == 'png' && $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) && !$force_type) {
        $file_type = 'png';
    }

    if (!$src_width) {
        return !($error = self::ERROR_FILE_WIDTH);
    }
    if (!$dst_width) {
        $dst_width = $src_width;
    }
    if (!$dst_height) {
        $dst_height = $src_height;
    }

    $width_diff = $dst_width / $src_width;
    $height_diff = $dst_height / $src_height;

    $ps_image_generation_method = Configuration::get('PS_IMAGE_GENERATION_METHOD');
    if ($width_diff > 1 && $height_diff > 1) {
        $next_width = $src_width;
        $next_height = $src_height;
    } else {
        if ($ps_image_generation_method == 2 || (!$ps_image_generation_method && $width_diff > $height_diff)) {
            $next_height = $dst_height;
            $next_width = round(($src_width * $next_height) / $src_height);
            $dst_width = (int)(!$ps_image_generation_method ? $dst_width : $next_width);
        } else {
            $next_width = $dst_width;
            $next_height = round($src_height * $dst_width / $src_width);
            $dst_height = (int)(!$ps_image_generation_method ? $dst_height : $next_height);
        }
    }

    if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($src_file)) {
        return !($error = self::ERROR_MEMORY_LIMIT);
    }

    $tgt_width  = $dst_width;
    $tgt_height = $dst_height;

    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_width, $dst_height);

    // If image is a PNG and the output is PNG, fill with transparency. Else fill with white background.
    if ($file_type == 'png' && $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        imagealphablending($dest_image, false);
        imagesavealpha($dest_image, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($dest_image, 0, 0, $dst_width, $dst_height, $transparent);
    } else {
        $white = imagecolorallocate($dest_image, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefilledrectangle($dest_image, 0, 0, $dst_width, $dst_height, $white);
    }

    $src_image = ImageManager::create($type, $src_file);
    if ($rotate) {
        $src_image = imagerotate($src_image, $rotate, 0);
    }

    if ($dst_width >= $src_width && $dst_height >= $src_height) {
        imagecopyresized($dest_image, $src_image, (int)(($dst_width - $next_width) / 2), (int)(($dst_height - $next_height) / 2), 0, 0, $next_width, $next_height, $src_width, $src_height);
    } else {
        ImageManager::imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $src_image, (int)(($dst_width - $next_width) / 2), (int)(($dst_height - $next_height) / 2), 0, 0, $next_width, $next_height, $src_width, $src_height, $quality);
    }
    $write_file = ImageManager::write($file_type, $dest_image, $dst_file);
    @imagedestroy($src_image);
    return $write_file;
}
```

I also tried to change **quality parameter** to **100** or even changed image format to PNG in prestashop - no changes.

What else can I change to fix this quality issues? Any ideas?

Comment: You could try using Imagick instead of GD and resize with an efficient filter. `$thumb = new Imagick('image.jpg'); $thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);` but you'll have to rewrite this function entirely.

Comment: I considered it too but thought maybe there is something easier to implement,